# Remove duplication item from combobox auto added value from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, combobox

I'm using SQL Server 2012 and developing a Windows forms application in C# with VS2013. I have code for auto-adding item from SQL Server to combobox :

```
void comboboxadd()
{
    SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(global::BeautyShop.Properties.Settings.Default.BeautyMaConnectionString);
    cnn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmm = new SqlCommand("select SupName from MPham group by SupName order by SupName asc", cnn);

    try
    {
        SqlDataReader dr = cmm.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            comboBox2.Items.Add(dr["SupName"]);
        }

        dr.Close();
        dr.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

My problem is : when I have same item on `SupName` column (not primary key), item will be added to combobox, too.

Example:

```
SupName   
-----------
ABC  
Joli  
ABC  
Str  
Joli
```

And the combobox item list is :

```
-----------    
ABC  
Joli  
ABC  
Str  
Joli  
-----------
```

I want my combobox list to be like this:

```
ABC  
Joli  
Str
```

How can I do this ?
Thanks for support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You just need to change your query:

no need to use `group by`

try

```
select distinct SupName from MPham order by SupName asc
```

See About [Sql Distinct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176104.aspx) Here

Answer (score 3):

By chaining your SQL query to select distinct items only like this

```
SqlCommand cmm = new SqlCommand(
   @"select Distinct SupName 
       from MPham 
   group by SupName 
   order by SupName asc", cnn);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try this

```
    void comboboxadd()
    {
        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(global::BeautyShop.Properties.Settings.Default.BeautyMaConnectionString);
        cnn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmm = new SqlCommand("select SupName from MPham group by SupName order by SupName asc", cnn);
        try
        {
            SqlDataReader dr = cmm.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                //Check here if item does not exist then add it.
                if(!comboBox2.Items.Contains(dr["SupName"]))
                     comboBox2.Items.Add(dr["SupName"]);
            }
            dr.Close();
            dr.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: This's a solution. Thanks so much.